# Fowarding from Apache to Tomcat breaks Grails rest api calls

Tags: apache, rest, tomcat, grails

Here is my setup: Apache virtual host listens on port 80, redirects to Tomcat at localhost:8080/webapp. Here is my virtual host settings:

```
<VirtualHost xxx>
ServerAdmin xxx
DocumentRoot "xxx"
ServerName xxx
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /webapp http://localhost:8080/webapp
ProxyPassReverse /webapp http://localhost:8080/webapp
RedirectMatch (.*) xxx/webapp
<Location "/">
# Configurations specific to this location. Add what you need.
# For instance, you can add mod_proxy_html directives to fix
# links in the HTML code. See link at end of this page about using
# mod_proxy_html.


# Allow access to this proxied URL location for everyone.
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>
```

I have a Grails Domain Class setup as a resource like so:

```
@Resource(uri='/agegroup',formats=['json'],readOnly=true)
class AgeGroup { ...}
```

This works as expected, i can browse to http://www.example.com/webapp/agegroup everything works fine. Here's the problem... I have a restful controller that I want to call at /api. This works running localhost:8080/webapp in Tomcat and calling /api, but not with Apache forwarding. Here is the controller:

```
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*
import static org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.*
import groovy.json.*

class ApiController extends RestfulController{
    static responseFormats = [index: ['json']]
... }
```

So my question is, how do I make rest calls to this controller that will work when forwarded by Apache to /webapp? I think what I might need is a way to tell Grails to map ApiController somewhere. I've also tried UrlMappings.groovy, but no luck.

**Update:**

I've added serverURL and app context to Config.grooy, no luck:

```
grails.serverURL = "http://example.com"
grails.app.context="/webapp"
```

Also, I used AJP protocol to forward with Apache instead of http, updated vhost config:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /webapp ajp://localhost:8009/webapp
ProxyPassReverse /webapp ajp://localhost:8009/webapp
RedirectMatch (.*) ajp:/xxx/webapp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is not an Apache/Tomcat problem... but something with Grails. I am not what specifically fixed this issue, but it had something to do with the rest controller. I recreated that specific rest controller and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If the Web App is running under two contexts so `/webapp` and `/api` then you need your `VirtualHost` to also contain:

```
ProxyPass /api http://localhost:8080/api
ProxyPassReverse /api http://localhost:8080/api
```

If your Rest API is running under `/webapp/api` then I would suggest hitting it in Chrome or Firefox and seeing what the Network tab shows for the request in the Developer Tools.

Comment: The api is not running under a different context, its part of the /webapp application. If running on localhost:8080/webapp/api. I can browse to /api just fine, but when pushing to the server, and having apache forward with the virtual host, I cannot reach the link through the browser, I get 404 not found.